# powershell script loop that runs two python files

Tags: powershell

I would like to use powershell script in windows 10 that calls a python file, waits for completion, then calls another, waits for completion and loops this forever.

I know how to run one in a loop but know nothing of powershell scripts. 
I am however fimaliar with Dos batch files and loops.

something like this:

```
while ($true) 
{
start-Process -wait .\python1.py
start-Process -wait .\python2.py
}
```

This command does what I want with one file from powershell prompt

```
while ($true) {start-Process -wait .\python1.py}
```

Comment: Where you said "something like this" is almost correct; all you need is to separate the two commands with `;` (PowerShell's command separator character).

Comment: Note that your first statement works just fine, and could even be entered / pasted as such at the PowerShell prompt. PowerShell statements on their own line never need a statement _terminator_, and commands inside `{ ... }` can always span multiple lines. However, as Bill states, you do need `;` to separate multiple statements on the _same_ line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while ($true) { start-Process -wait .\python1.py ; start-Process -wait .\python2.py }
```

Thanks Bill!